# Parametrization of A1 notation cell value in python

Tags: python, excel, cell

How can I dynamically define the cell location. For example, suppose I have a worksheet consisting of six rows.

I am able to get the rows count using `Count_Row = df.shape[0]` but not sure how do I reference `Count_Row` parameter in the below statement.

```
worksheet.conditional_format('A1:A[Count_Row]',
                            {'type':'cell','criteria': '>=','value':0,'format':format2})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `.format` (or any other string interpolation method of your liking):

```
worksheet.conditional_format('A1:A{}'.format(Count_Row),
                            {'type':'cell','criteria': '>=','value':0,'format':format2})
```

Comment: Thank you, appreciate your help sir

Answer (score 0):

Same as DeepSpace's answer, but using [`f-string`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) instead:

```
worksheet.conditional_format(f'A1:A{Count_Row}',
                            {'type':'cell','criteria': '>=','value':0,'format':format2})
```

Comment: Thank you, this works too. Glad to get help from strangers